# Python websocket client - Method to figure out if connection is open

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I am working with the python websocket library websocket_client (https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/)

I was wondering if there is a way that I can check if the websocket connection is still open (something like what I have below)

```
if ws.connected == True:
    break
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you may use `ws.connected`

But be careful that it will not be updated unless there is a call, so perhaps you can write a function that uses `recv()` to receive an empty data, after that, you can check `ws.connected`.

```
def is_ws_connected(ws):
    ws.recv()
    return ws.connected
```